# How to send two different emails on one button click using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send two emails at the same time when the user submits contact form. One email to the website owner and other to the user as autoresponse. I have been trying to do this for about last 4 hours and tried different solutions on internet but I am totally lost. Here is my code to send an email

```
  public function contactForm(Request $request)
{
    $parameters = Input::get();
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $inquiryType = Input::get('type_inquiry');
    foreach ([
                 'contactmessage' => 'Message',
                 'email'        => 'Email',
                 'phone'        => 'Phone',
                 'first_name'   => 'Contact Name',
                 'g-recaptcha-response' => 'Captcha',
             ] as $key => $label) {
        if (!isset($parameters[$key]) || empty($parameters[$key])) {
            return response()->json(
                [
                    'success' => false,
                    'error'   => "{$label} cannot be empty",
                ]
            );
        }
    }


   $recipients = 'abc@gmail.com';

    // if page set, try to get recipients from the page settings
    if (Input::get('page_id')) {
        $page = Page::find(Input::get('page_id'));
        if ($page && !empty($page->recipients)) {
            $recipients = explode(',', $page->recipients);
        }
    }

    try {
            $res = Mail::send(
                'emails.contact',
                $parameters,
                function (Message $message) use ($recipients) {
                    $message->subject('Contact message');
                    if (is_array($recipients)) {
                        // email to first address
                        $message->to(array_shift($recipients));
                        // cc others
                        $message->cc($recipients);
                    } else {
                        $message->to($recipients);
                    }
                }
            );

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(
            [
                'success' => false,
                'error'   => $e->getMessage(),
            ]
        );
    }

 if($inquiryType == 'Rental Inquiry'){
    Mail::send(
        'emails.autoresponse',
        '',
        function (Message $message) use ($email) {
            $message->subject('Thank you for inquiring');
            if (is_array($email) {
                // email to first address
                $message->to(array_shift($email);
                // cc others
                $message->cc($email);
            } else {
                $message->to($email);
            }
        }
    );
  }
    return response()->json(
        [
            'success' => $res,
        ]
    );
}
```

I have tried to do the same thing by different methods but none of them are working. Please help me. This is the first time I am sending multiple emails using laravel. I think I am doing a big and silly mistake somewhere.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes, its just not showing the page - Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: do you know how to enable debug? if yes then enable that and share error screenshot here.

Comment: It may be your `Input::get()` as I'm not sure if that returns something that's interable in a foreach loop.  Might need to change that to `Input::all()`.  Without seeing the full error, it's hard to tell for sure.

Comment: Debug mode is set to true in .env but still its not showing any error.

Comment: Check your server logs.

Comment: Everything is working fine without if($inquiryType == 'Rental Inquiry'){ }. When I am placing this piece of code its not showing the page.

Comment: In case of 'Rental Inquiry', the variable `$res` is not defined anywhere in that check which is returned at the end.

Comment: Website has stopped working suddenly. Its just saying www.example.com is currently unable to handle this request. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please check `Laravel` logs in your source directory at this path `storage/logs/laravel-{latest-date}.log` , end of the relevant file.

Comment: I am using FTP account and laravel.log file is too big to download. Its taking ages to open, its about 438 MB. Now, the website is working but email issue is still there.

Comment: You shouldn't be testing this live. If you're on a nix based system then login to ssh and use tail command to check the recent bit of log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing closing parenthesis near `is_array($email)`

```
$message->subject('Thank you for inquiring');
if (is_array($email)) {
```

Also i would you use laravel's validator to check for required input. Another suggestion would be to use queues for mails. Sending two mails in a single request might cause your page load time to increase significantly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the parenthesis error but still its not working.

Comment: Reading your comments i'm surprised your having this in production and trying to get the production log. If you're gonna debug and fix this, then you should be working locally. Also checking the log file would give you the correct issue with this. I still think you haven't enabled debug in your application. Check the logs and let us know what you see, so that we can help you better.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I am helpless, my client asked me to do all the changes on live server. Anyways your hint towards closing parenthesis helped me a lot and there was a parenthesis missing after $message->to(array_shift($email); . Now, its working. Thank you.

Comment: Ah i missed that one. Glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is create one Laravel Jobs

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan migrate

php artisan make:job SendEmail
```

Edit your `.env`

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Edit your `app /Jobs/SendEmail.php`

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;

class SendEmail extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $subject;
    protected $view;
    protected $data;
    protected $email;

    /**
     * SendEmail constructor.
     * @param $subject
     * @param $data
     * @param $view
     * @param $email
     */
    public function __construct($subject, $data, $view, $email)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     * @param $mailer
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $email = $this->email;
        $subject = $this->subject;
        $view = $this->view;
        $mailer->send($view, $this->data,
            function ($message) use ($email, $subject) {
                $message->to($email)
                    ->subject($subject);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And handle in your controller

```
use App\Jobs\SendEmail;

public function contactForm(Request $request) {
    //TODO Configure Subject
    $subjectOwner    = 'Your Email Subject For Owner';
    $subjectUser    = 'Your Email Subject For User';
    //TODO Configure Email
    $ownerEmail = 'ownerEmail@gmail.com';
    $userEmail = 'userEmail@gmail.com';
    //TODO Configure Data Email send to email blade viewer
    $dataEmail = [
        'lang'                  => 'en',
        'user_name'             => 'User Name'
    ];
    //emails.owner mean emails/owner.blade.php
    //emails.admin mean emails/admin.blade.php
    $jobOwner = (new SendEmail($subjectOwner, $dataEmail,  "emails.owner" , $ownerEmail))->onQueue('emails');
    dispatch($jobOwner);
    $jobUser = (new SendEmail($subjectUser, $dataEmail,  "emails.admin" , $userEmail))->onQueue('emails');
    dispatch($jobUser);
}
```

And try command

```
//IF You using Laravel 5.2
php artisan queue:listen --queue=emails
//IF You using Laravel >5.3
php artisan queue:work
```